# Slutsky's Theorem - sufficient conditions for product to converge to zero

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Consider two sequences of random variables, $\,\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ and suppose that $\,a_n\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}0$. Provided that $\,b_n\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}Z$ with $Z\sim F$ for a given distribution $F$, I understood that Slutsky's theorem dictates that $$a_n\,b_n\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}0\,Z$$such that effectively
$$a_n\,b_n\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}0.$$
However, when defining "constant" random variables $\,a_n=1/n$ and $b_n=n$, it clearly follows that 
$$a_n\,b_n\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}1.$$
I'd very much appreciate, if someone could briefly delineate a set of high-level conditions on $\{b_n\}$ that would be sufficient for the result that$$a_n\,b_n\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}0\quad\text{provided that }\,\,\,a_n\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}0.$$
E.g. does it suffice to assume that $b_n$ is $O_p(1)$ - which would clearly be violated in my counter example.

Thank you very much for your time.

Best regards,
Jon

Comment: The reason why $a_nb_n \to_p 0$ is not working when $b_n = n$ is that $(b_n)$ does not converge to real-valued distribution, i.e. $b_n\to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response. Just to clarify; so if the limiting distribution of $b_n$ was defined on a support $\Xi\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, that would be sufficient for $a_n\,b_n\to_p0$ in general?

Comment: Yes, you are right! If the limiting distribution, say $b$ satisfies $\Bbb P(b=\pm\infty)=0$, then Slutsky theorem holds

Comment: Alright, thank you so much. Sounds straightforward enough.